# Azure Logic App - Loop through email addresses and send to slack

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am attempting my first Logic App, which will trigger from an email. It will then look for any email addresses in the body of the email, and send an individual slack message to a channel with the email address as the text.

So far, all I can do is post one message to the channel with an array of the email addresses.
Here's what I am doing...

When an email arrives, first initialize an array :
[image]

Then I convert the email body to text (to remove any HTML)
Then I find any addresses in the above text :
[image]

Then I set the above emails variable with :

```
createArray(outputs('Find_Email_Address_in_Email')['body'])
```

And Finally I send a slack message in a loop based on the Emails array :

[image]

What gets posted to slack is :
[image]

(The whole array, when I want it to run once for each email in the list).

I think I am either setting the array incorrectly, or the for each isnt set up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
On the Set Variable section, Instead out using the output straight from the JS execution, I convert it to JSON first like :

```
json(outputs('Previous_Step_Name')['body'])
```